# Hide null values on parameter value

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, null, ssrs-2012

I have a stored parameter with a where clause between start and end dates that includes null values:

```
WHERE a.date is null OR a.date between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

These null values are obviously being selected when any parameter value (date range) is chosen in my SSRS report.... my question is, is there a way to not show these null values when a specific parameter value (date range) is selected?

P.S. I can hide the row where parameter equals a value and the a.date field is null in Row Visibility within a SSRS report but I want to avoid this if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the filtering conditions:

```
WHERE a.date is null AND (@startDate is NOT NULL OR @EndDate IS NOT NULL) OR
      a.date between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Massive help

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that handles using any combination of filtering on `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`:

```
where a.date is NULL or (
  ( @StartDate is NULL or @StartDate <= a.date ) and
  ( @EndDate is NULL or a.date <= @EndDate ) )
```

Aside: If `a.date` is not a `Date` but also contains a time, e.g. is a `DateTime`, then an end-date test that includes the entire last day up to, but not including, midnight is `a.date < DateAdd( day, 1, @EndDate )`.